# Given an Inconsistent Set, find a Consistent Subset

Tags: logic

I'm a student learning first-order logic, so forgive me if this is elementary.

If I'm given an inconsistent set (that is, a set $\Sigma$ that can be used to show $\phi$ and $\lnot\phi$), is it possible to form a set $\Gamma$ of out of its elements such that $\Gamma$ is consistent?

$\Gamma$ need not be maximally-consistent, as I'm told that is impossible to prove. Just looking for a general algorithm to do this. I feel like it involves resolution (as we've been taught resolution), but I'm not sure.

Thanks!

Comment: Put `$` around the $\LaTeX$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Consider the case where $\Gamma$ is just a single sentence which is provably false (e.g. $\varphi\land\lnot\varphi$ for any sentence $\varphi$). If we require that the consistent subset is non-empty, then there is only one possible subset.

Comment: That being the empty set? Starting from the empty set, however, can I not keep adding sentences from $\Sigma$ to $\Gamma$ one by one, and then resolving to see if my new set is consistent?

Comment: @John: Yes, you can always add one sentence at a time to see if you are still with a consistent set. But note that it is possible that all sentences are simply false, so only the empty set is a consistent subset; and more importantly you only asked for an example (which I assumed meant a nontrivial one, i.e. a non-empty example) for a consistent subset.

Answer (score 3):

Here are two easy observations:

Given any set of sentences $\Gamma$, the empty theory is a consistent subset of $\Gamma$.

If $\Gamma$ consists entirely of tautologically false sentences (for example, sentences of the form $\phi\land\lnot\phi$) then every nonempty subset of $\Gamma$ is inconsistent.

**Edit:** I've noticed that in your question, you're looking for an *algorithm* to find a consistent subset of $\Gamma$. This is impossible in general, because you can't even algorithmically recognize a consistent set of first-order sentences when you're handed one. In a sufficiently complicated first-order language (and you don't need much - a binary relation symbol or a binary function symbol is already enough), the set of tautologies, and hence the set of inconsistent sentences, is [undecidable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decidability_%28logic%29).

On the other hand, you can use Zorn's Lemma and compactness to show that $\Gamma$ *has* maximally consistent subtheories.

Comment: Starting from the empty set, however, can I not keep adding sentences from Σ to Γ one by one, and then resolving to see if my new set is consistent?

Comment: Sure - but you might not get very far. For example if $\Gamma$ consists only of tautologically false sentences! I've also just made an edit to my post.

Answer (score 3):

The empty set.${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$